# Add a new command into Run menu in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ v6.7.9.2 in Windows 7.

I want to add a "***PHP Manual***" item for the downloaded PHP Help file (.chm) in the **Run** menu

I tried adding

```
<Command name=“PHP Manual” Ctrl=“yes” Alt=“yes” Shift=“no” Key=“116”>
     hh.exe “ms-its:C:\PHP Manual\php_manual_en.chm::/function.$(CURRENT_WORD).html”
</Command>
```

to

> “Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml”

, but it didn’t make any changes in Run menu.

Then i tried adding the above command in

> “%APPDATA%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml”

, but still it didn’t reflect any changes.

So how can i add the above command in Run menu

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is the Run menu (F5). Type in the command you want to execute. Run it to make sure it does want you want it to do,
then open Run again  (F5), the command will still be there, and press 'Save...'
Select an unused shortcut from the options presented, and after that your shortcut should work.
I use it with my java project, I have a 'compile.bat' in my project folder, and assigned Ctrl-F1 to run 'compile.bat' directly from within notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, its because of me trying to edit the modifications from Notepad++ itself.

When i tried from another editor, it helped.

Help found from Notepad++ Community 
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/10113/how-to-add-a-new-command-in-run-menu

Comment: That sounds odd. After editing the files in notepad++, did you close and restart notepad++?

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson yes i did close and restart notepad++ before. Strangely if you edit & save from Notepad++, when you close the N++ it overwrites the prev edition.

Comment: Not that strange if it can be modified by Notepad++ (from menus, for instance) - it will save its changes on exit. This probably also happen if you edit it in a different editor with Notepad++ open; the changes will be overwritten when Notepad++ is closed. I think the cause of the issue is better described as "notepad++ overwrites its config files when closed", than "can't edit notepad++' config files from within notepad++". (But maybe that's just me). If you saved the file with a different name, closed notepad++, renamed the saved file to the correct name, it should work.